# how to use spanish ,french ,chinese ,german keyboard in app

Tags: iphone, uikeyboard, uikeyboardtype

i want to have different language (spanish,german,french,chinese and so on)  keyboard in my app.

How can i use different language keyboard in my app.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot control the language of the keyboard. The user chooses which keyboards they would like available via the settings application and can toggle between them using the globe icon on the keyboard(PFA Image).When the keyboard is opened it will open to the most recently used keyboard.

[image]).

Answer (score 0):

It‘s up to your settings's keyboard.If you want to use so many keyboard,your iphone should add those keyboard first.

Comment: my question is that i have 10 different view and each view i want to use different language keyboard ........is this possible .......can i explicitly assign keyboard